# How to create a Google sign-up sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-drive-sharing

Is it possible to create a Google sign-up form accessible via iPhone etc. without the need for a Google account? We find we can open from a computer but not a phone if you don't have an account.

Comment: Use Google Forms. But a Google Account is needed.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 15 times. It doesn't include the question as a practical detailed question about using a specific web application. It barely states a problem and a requirement, but this is not a help desk or help wanted billboard. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue that you do not want the creator of the form to need a Google Account or is the issue that you do not want the people submitting a form to need a Google Account?

If you do not want the creator to need a Google Account, you are out of luck but there is not really a purpose to this because then you would not be able to see responses.

I am guessing that your issue is that you do not want the submitters to need a Google Account. This is an easy fix. Simply go to the form's settings and uncheck this option and users will not be required to log in to submit the form. [image]

More information on getting started can be found [here](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/forms/get-started/).